# destructor of a list delete virtual c++, basic questions

Tags: c++, list, pointers, memory, destructor

I have

```
class Derived : public Base
```

1. If I have a `std::list<G>` how do I free the list?
2. If I have a `std::list<G*>` in `A`, how do I free the list?
3. Destructor - which one should be virtual, `A`'s destructor or `B`'s destructor?
4. When do I use `list.clear()` and when to use `list.empty()`?
5. Same questions 1-2 but with a `std::vector`?

here's my code:

```
class Movie{
    list<Worker*> workersInMovie;
    list<G> g;

    Movie::~Movie() {
        for(list::<Worker*>::iterator it = workersInMovie.begin();
            it != workersInMovie.end(); ++it;)
            delete it;

        g.clear();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question: (list)

- Your list will be automatically deleted on class destroy

Second question: (list pointers)

- On destructor of your class you must delete all pointers. A trick is used `std::shared_ptr<>` that will automatically destroy your pointer when nobody have a reference to it

About the code that you propose:

Is better use `auto` (if you are using C11 or newer) than `list::<Worker*>::iterator`

```
for(auto it=workersInMovie.begin(); it!=workersInMovie.end(); it++){           
   delete *it; 
 }
```

}

Comment: so i editted my post, is this the right code to delete?

Comment: cant use that.. is my code right adding delete *it?

Comment: yes, your iterator is ok, but your `++it;` must be `++it` (without `;`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to free the pointers yourself. The list doesn't have a specialization for pointers, it knows nothing about the data stored in the list. And even if it knew it stored pointers (and had a specialization for it), then it could *still* not know if the pointers should be deleted or not, what if you store pointers to objects that wasn't created by `new`?

Answer (score 0):

1. You call `std::list::clear` or let the destructor do it's job
2. You call `delete` before destruction on every element (only if it was allocated with `new`, of course)
3. Base class destructor has to be declared `virtual`, it will also propagate to derived class' member function declaration
4. `std::list::clear` clears the list, `std::list::empty` returns a `bool` that tells you whether the list is empty or not (too hard to check the reference?)
5. Same as with `std::list`

The cleanest possible version of the destructor (still using raw pointers):

```
Movie::~Movie() {
    for(auto x : workersInMovie)
        delete x;

    // no need to clear, std::list's destructor called afterwards
}
```

Working version using iterator:

```
Movie::~Movie() {
    for(auto it = workersInMovie.begin();
        it != workersInMovie.end(); ++it)
        delete *it;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it looks like it, except `g.empty()` should be `g.clear()` according to (4).

Comment: are you sure about base class destructor being virtual ?
i thought its derived class

Comment: and btw, can I declare a class as abstract even thought it has no abstract method?

Comment: 1. You declare method `virtual` for the class, from which further down the chain of derived classes you want polymorphysm to happen. 2. You can't, that's the definition. You can make the destructor pure virtual, if you want to make class abstract.

Comment: @Mooly And if `Movie` is the base class, `Movie::~Movie` should be `virtual`.

Comment: @Mooly Now, I also see that the destructor should be public and that you have superfluous `;` after `++it`.

Comment: if I make a destructor of base class pure virtual, and base class has a pointer d*, isn't it problematic? because that pointer of base class will never be deleted..

Comment: You're making this broad. One question per post, right? Also, there are existing QA about this stuff.